# Finite product and coproduct are the same in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, universal-property

I am working with the following definition of abelian category.

a) It has a $0$ object.

b)  Every morphism has a kernel and a cokernel. Every monomorphismis a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel.

c) It has all finite products and finite coproducts.

Now, my definition does not make it explicit that finite products and coproducts are the same, but I know that that holds for all abelian categories.

More precisely, I would like to prove that for all objects $A$ and $B$, the morphism $ (id_A, id_B) : A \bigoplus B \longrightarrow A \times B$ is iso. Note that the morphism I've written can be constructed by using the universal properties of product and coproduct.

Comment: I think you need addition to show this. Is your category enriched in Abelian groups? Also, the natural morphism goes in the other direction: $(\pi_A,\pi_B):A\times B\to A+B$.

Comment: @Berci I've read that those axioms allow you to define an enrichment over Ab.

Comment: You want to read the first chapter of Freyd’s book about abelian categories. They start from your definition and show that the abelian enrichment and biproducts are a consequence. I do not feel like copying the arguments from a whole book chapter, but if you can t access the book, then I can sketch the relevant steps in an answer.

Comment: @Merle It's ok, I found the book. The proof is indeed quite long, maybe I too will limit myself to sketching it in the report I'm writing.